# Caching big data in .NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, caching, redis, memcached

I have a Web API that provides complex statistical/forecast data. I have one endpoint that can take even 20s to complete, so I started looking at caching to boots the performance. My situation is very different from these described in many examples, so I need help.

Long story short, the method returns a batch of forecasts and statistics for item. For single item, it's as quick as 50ms, that's good. But there is also a method (very complex) that needs 2000-3000 items AT ONCE, to calculate different statistics. And this is a problem.

There are probably around 250,000 items in the database, around 200M rows in one table. The good part is: Table only updates ONCE per day and I would need around 1GB of data (around 80M "optimized" rows).

So my idea was, once per day (I know exactly when) the API would query, transform, optimize and put into memory 1GB of data from that table, and during the day, it will be lighting fast.

My question is, is it a good idea? Should I use some external provider (like Memcached or Redis) or just a singleton list with proper locking using semaphores etc?

If Memcache, how can I do it? I don't want to cache this table "as is". It's too big. I need to do some transformation first.

Thanks!

Comment: my point is that you should process not once a day, maybe you should split jobs into many chunks and process them in parallel and then put into RAM

Comment: @DmytroShabanov but once per day, the entire table is removed, and brand new data is inserted.

Comment: the problem is that if you need to proceed a lot of data, Memcached not solved your problem, its just store its data and speed up get requests.If you need processing this should be in the background using scheduler (quartz or hangfire), so user can get precalculated items.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good solution if you are not limited by server RAM, imo. Since it's .Net Core you can try `System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache`